# How to remove the empty column month in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

1) I am using fullCalendar. ByDefault I want to show one month. Like 30 days or 31 days. If Feb means 28 days or 29 days.

2) Please look  the fiddle.

3) It has showing one month and next month's half dates also displaying. I dont want t show that.

Please help me how can I remove that.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jyxs6Lc/3/)

Please look at this fiddle,

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 header: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
 },
 defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
 editable: true,
});
$("td.fc-day.fc-widget-content").each(function( index ) {
    var start = moment('2014-06-04'); //start date from start date input
        var end = moment('2014-06-18'); //end date from end date input
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
        var date = $(this).data('date'); //get current date in loop
        var day = moment(date); //create a moment
        
        //if day is greater than start date and less than end date, display.
        if(day > start && day < end) {
         $(this).append("<span style='font-size: 30px;font-weight: 600;color: green;'>"+random+"%</span>");
        }
    });
```

```css
body {
 margin-top: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
}

#calendar {
 width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
Start Date :<input type="text" id="endDate" name="end_datum" class="input_text" value=""> 
End date :<input type="text" id="endDate" name="end_datum" class="input_text" value=""></br></br></br></br>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide content of `fc-other-month` and set height of widget content div like this.

```
.fc-other-month div {
  display: none;
}

.fc-widget-content div {
  height: 107px;
}
```

Updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3jyxs6Lc/5/

Comment: @Naendra CM Thank you  so much

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  td.fc-other-month
  {
       visibility: hidden;
  }
```

After set the visibility to hidden, you will have to alter the method

```
if(event.start.getMonth() !== view.start.getMonth()) { return false; }
```